# Автообновление чата MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, chat

Пытаюсь написать игровой чат Web <> Server на PHP. От сервера чат пишет в MySQL, но выводит результат (последние 70 сообщений) только при загрузке страници. Хотелось бы сделать автообновление. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать? Не очень хочется бомбить MySQL запросами каждую секунду

Comment: для таких штук вам нужно смотреть в сторону сокетов.

Comment: WebSocket(как сказали выше) или Ajax + LongPooling.

Comment: посмотрите на сетевой фреймворк Swoole, там уже присутствует весь функционал который понадобится.